# How to Create a List of Pandas Series from a List of Dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [
   { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
   { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }
]
```

I need to convert the values of each of those 'frame' keys to a Pandas Series such as the following so that I can plot later on:

```
aaa 50
bbb 12
ccc 23
ddd 72
```

After reading [this](https://realpython.com/pandas-python-explore-dataset/#getting-to-know-pandas-data-structures) article, I realized that Pandas Series behave like dictionaries where indices can be strings.

So far, what I have only done is be able to iterate `mylist` as follows:

```
for element in mylist :
    print(type(element['frame']), element['frame'])
```

Which outputs:

```
<class 'dict'> {'aaa': 50}
<class 'dict'> {'bbb': 12}
<class 'dict'> {'ccc': 23}
<class 'dict'> {'ddd': 72}
```

Is there any way to convert this list to a Pandas Series object? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `pd.Series(dictionary_variable)`

As the example you shown, I provide this code for your problem, hope to be helpful:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [
   { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
   { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }
]
return_dict = {}
for dictionary in mylist:
    inner_dict = dictionary["frame"]
    key = list(inner_dict.keys())[0]
    value = inner_dict[key]
    return_dict[key] = value

series = pd.Series(return_dict)
print(type(series))
print(series)
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
aaa    50
bbb    12
ccc    23
ddd    72
dtype: int64
```

But if you want to make pandas series from **each** of the frames so you just need:

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [
   { 'frame': { 'aaa': 50 } },
   { 'frame': { 'bbb': 12 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ccc': 23 } },
   { 'frame': { 'ddd': 72 } }
]

return_dict = {}
for dictionary in mylist:
    inner_dict = dictionary["frame"]
    series = pd.Series(inner_dict)
    print(type(series), series, sep=" ")
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> aaa    50
dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> bbb    12
dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ccc    23
dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ddd    72
dtype: int64
```